# How to fix JSLint "missing new" error

Tags: javascript, jslint

Code below passed through [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) causes an error:

> Problem at line 8 character 9: Missing 'new'.
>
> ResizeGrid();

How to fix?

```
"use strict";

var ResizeGrid;

function t() {
    var x;
    if (x) {
        ResizeGrid();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Tick `Tolerate uncapitalized constructors` or rename to `resizeGrid();` to prevent lint from assuming its a function constructor (although calling an undefined `var` like that will raise other errors).

Answer (score 5):

You should name functions with a lower case initial letter, unless they are intended as constructors. If they are intended as constructors, you should be calling them with `new`.